# Get cursor position in LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

How to get cursor position in libgdx and apply it to sprite? Like this?
[image]

I want my sprite to have the direction pointed wherever my cursor is in the screen.I search libgdx examples but i cant find any examples related to that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Get cursor position

If you're polling for input, use `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` to get the current mouse x and y coordinates.  (The doc says its only relevant for touch, but the code [looks like it reports raw mouse values](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglInput.java#L209) regardless of button state.)

If you're using an `InputProcessor` you can use one of:

- [touchMoved callback](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#touchMoved%28int,%20int%29) (on older libGDX versions)
- [mouseMoved callback](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html#mouseMoved%28int,%20int%29) (on newer libGDX versions)

to receive input events from a mouse with no buttons pressed.

#### Apply position to sprite

Update a [`Vector2`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) that points from the current sprite position to the cursor position.  This can be your Sprite's heading.  You'll want to rotate the sprite's heading to match this vector.

Use [`Vector2.angle()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#angle%28%29) to compute the angle of this vector, and set your sprite's rotation to this.  (This is relative to the positive X axis,so you may need to add a constant if you want it relative to the Y axis.)

Comment: what's next? I went through a million combinations and nothing came out https://gist.github.com/navifundendi/e0934a597acf94f261129b14fb17b9f3

Answer (score 6):

I usually track my mouse into world coordinates like this:

```
    // variables
    private final Vector2 mouseInWorld2D = new Vector2();
    private final Vector3 mouseInWorld3D = new Vector3();
    private final OrthographicCamera cam; 
    .
    .
    .
    //in render() code
    mouseInWorld3D.x = Gdx.input.getX();
    mouseInWorld3D.y = Gdx.input.getY();
    mouseInWorld3D.z = 0;
    cam.unproject(mouseInWorld3D);
    mouseInWorld2D.x = mouseInWorld3D.x;
    mouseInWorld2D.y = mouseInWorld3D.y;
```

Then, I can use mouseInWorld2D to access mouse coordinates (relative to the scene/world) in my game. A sprite can track that coordinate very easy and compute its angle and direction.

Comment: what's next? I went through a million combinations and nothing came out https://gist.github.com/navifundendi/e0934a597acf94f261129b14fb17b9f3

Comment: I dont understand "whats next"...  mouseInWorld2D.x and  mouseInWorld2D.y stores the mouse coords

Comment: This code is very cool!! Thank you very much!