# mouse position is off in LibGDX with fullscreen borderless window in windows

Tags: windows, libgdx

I'm writing a libGDX application, using the Lwjgl3Launcher. Everything works nicely, there's just one problem:

I'm trying to create a borderless fullscreen window like this:

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val displayMode = Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration.getDisplayMode()
        Lwjgl3Application(Orbitrucker("assets/native", displayMode), Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration().apply {
            setTitle("Orbitrucker")
            // TODO: There's mouse cursor offset when a borderless window has screen size!
            setWindowedMode(1920, 1080)
            setResizable(false)
            setDecorated(false)
            setAutoIconify(true)

        })
    }
```

Where the screen resolution is actually 1920x1080, everything *looks* fine. I.e. I get my application on the entire screen, with nothing else there (taskbar not visible).
*However*, the mouse behaves as though the taskbar was still visible, and the window was sitting on top of it. I.e. all the mouse Y coordinates are offset by the height of the Taskbar.

Surprisingly, I'm not really finding any information about this issue when googling, though I can't possibly be the first running into this. Maybe the solution is so simple it's not worth mentioning, but I haven't found it yet.

If the resolution is smaller than the entire screen, the mouse position is fine. If I don't set decorated to false, the position is fine (but then the taskbar is visible, so that's not what I want). With decorated set to false it all looks just like I want it, but apparently for the purpose of the mouse the taskbar is still there...

Answer (score 0):

Try
`setWindowedMode(1920, 1080)`
at the very end. Or specifically after
`setDecorated(false)`

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/6646

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: are you doing this mouseInWorld3D.x = Gdx.input.getX();
    mouseInWorld3D.y = Gdx.input.getY();
    cam.unproject(mouseInWorld3D); you need to unproject (btw I would still do setDecorated first)

Comment: Uhm, no, I don't think I'm doing that. Where exactly would I need to do that?

Comment: have a look here you need access to the camera even if its a 2d scene https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381031/get-cursor-position-in-libgdx (btw are you the real Uncle Bob ?)